# How can I add to row with highest primary key?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database, with a column I would like to update where the row is the most recently generated one, after searching for a while I found this solution

`UPDATE data SET Tricked = 'Affirmative' WHERE Identification = (SELECT MAX(Identification) FROM data);`

However this didn't work, I received no errors but it did nothing. What about it isn't allowing it to work?

Comment: If you're using MySQL, it keeps track of the last ID it auto-generated during the current connection.  And most PHP APIs will give you access to that, even if you have to say `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` or something.

Comment: It's best to use the last insert id as the MAX might give you the wrong id in a concurrent situation where more than one user is causing changes.

Comment: Is it possible the given session is not seeing the newly inserted rows?

Comment: I tried executing within phpmyadmin3 and it wouldnt let me do it with the FROM clause, so i took that out and it added afirmitive to all of the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is objecting to your use of the `SELECT` statement in the where clause on the table you're updating. You should see a response like this:

`Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'data' for update in FROM clause`

PHP solutions involving the `last_insert_id` only work for the lifetime of the session, and then only if no other user is inserting records, so won't be reliable.

Try this:

```
UPDATE data
  SET Tricked='Affirmative' 
  ORDER BY Identification DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() is per MySQL connection.  If you're looking to update the last record you inserted, it's far more reliable than any query that involves consulting the table.

Comment: @cHao So if someone else is inserting records, or the update command is executed from a session where no records have been inserted then the last_insert_id won't be reliable. See my answer above.

Comment: This worked perfectly, my webhosting service will not allow socket connection so i must use their service which is phpmyadmin3. Thank you Mike :)

Comment: @MikeW: If the problem is that the record in question wasn't updated during the current MySQL session, and the code no longer knows the ID of it, then there are far bigger architectural flaws.  Flaws that will only really show themselves if the site ever has significant/simultaneous activity.

Comment: @cHao There is much that is unsaid in this question. However, since the OP is using PHPMyAdmin to apply the update I think we can disregard issues of scalability for the time being.